# localStorage and Javascript Object with arrays, save Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, javascript-objects

I have the follwoing Components:

```
patientDiseasesStorage = new Object()
patientDiseasesStorage['p158246547'] = [1, 3, 8, 2, 5] //and many more of this with different p-number
```

I try now to save this Object/Array Combination

```
localStorage.setItem('patientDiseasesStorage', JSON.stringify(patientDiseasesStorage));
```

But when i try to read this back from localStorage it does not have the correct values:

```
patientDiseasesStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('patientDiseasesStorage'));
patientDiseasesStorage['p158246547'] is now undefined and not the array.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `p158246547` indeed a variable, and if so, does it have the same value in both cases?

Comment: I have a lot of these ID's. And I want to store the Arrays for those ID's and later to get the Arrays back from local storage with the same ID's

Comment: But is the actual ID stored in a variable called `p158246547`? Or is the ID itself supposed to be `p158246547`?

Comment: The id is the p158246547. The problem is not the storing and recieving od the array in the object. The problem is: After storing the the object in the localstorage and recieving it back, I am not able to restore it properly to recieve my array.

Comment: I corrected the quotes for the id value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `p158246547` is a string and not a variable name, it should have quotes around it:

```
patientDiseasesStorage['p158246547'] = [1, 3, 8, 2, 5] //and many more of this with different p-number
```

Use the quotes when you pull it back out of the localStorage as well.

Comment: the storing in the object and the reading from it is working. Only when I restored the object from the localStorage it's not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Latest Chrome works for me.

```
var a = [1, 2,3]
var obj = {'a': a}
obj.a
> [1, 2, 3]
localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj))
var obj2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('obj'))
obj2.a
> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Whenn i assign a new value to the object using the syntax object.newname than it works. But how do I assign things to an object when the name of the new value is stored in a variable?

Comment: @user1031990: I don't see the issue - if I change it to use `var obj = new Object(); obj['a'] = a` it all still works exactly the same - I copied and pasted your code verbatim and it worked fine... Can you make a jsFiddle that exemplifies the issue?